# Looking for Datalog containment utility

Tags: datalog

Given two Datalog programs `P1,P2` I am looking for a utility/library in any programming language that returns a boolean if the `P1 contained in P2`.

Comment: Since this is a [software recommendation question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199411/where-can-i-ask-a-question-about-finding-general-software-that-meets-certain-req), it's probably off-topic on Stack Overflow.